# Can I use the rate limit header to implement rate limitation directly on WSO2 ESB message processor?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am very new in **WSO2 ESB** and I have the following situation to deal with.

I have a **Message Processor** which extracts some XML messages from a queue and that send it to an external web service, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" messageStore="glisMessageStore" name="glisMessageProcessor" targetEndpoint="glisEndpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="client.retry.interval">100</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">4</parameter>
    <parameter name="member.count">1</parameter>
    <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">glisResponseSequence</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Disabled</parameter>
    <parameter name="interval">10</parameter>
    <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

Where the **glisResponseSequence.xml** contains a pretty complex behavior ending with a **callout** mediator that send the message to my external web service.

It works fine but now I have also to deal with the **rate limitation** concept.

When the **message processor** call the **glisResponseSequence.xml** sequence it ends with a **callout** mediator that send the message to my external web service that return a response containing headers like:

```
X-Rate-Limit-Limit
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining
X-Rate-Limit-Reset
```

Can I use these headers to instruct the **message processor** to wait to call the **glisResponseSequence.xml** sequence or something like this (to avoid to send too much request to the external web service)

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Custom+Message+Processor

Comment: @simar so do you think that this is not a standard behavior but that have to be manually implemented?

Comment: It is non standard for WSO2ESB. But i think it is possible to extract values of those headers and emulate managing rate limits.At least on simple level, to check if remaining

Comment: @simar Ok, so I will have a custom message processor (instead the used standard one) that will call the same sequence ending with the callout mediator. So what could be a smart strategy to access to the headers list inside the returned response? Because I think that this response is not into the message processor but in the sequence (but maybe I am doing wrong assertion)

Comment: One idea is to store the header values in some sort of map keyed by client Id and use this information in the front end sequence - the one that puts messages in the message store.